# CSS fit a div inside viewport while keeping aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

[image]

I would like to fit a div(red white box) in the center of the page. the black area represent the page layout
the div needs to be height 100% when width cannot be stretched to keep the aspect ratio, or width 100% when height cannot be stretched. I am not sure what property I should use to calculate

It is also important that the div do not overflow the page so no scrollbar will be shown

I have tried: setting `height: 100%; width: auto;` or `width: 100%; height: auto;` both can achieve half of the target but I need to combine them together

*update:
I have achieved with 1:1 aspect ratio with @Paulie_D 's answer, but what if the div needs to be 16:9 or 4:3?

Comment: What have you tried so far, what went wrong?

Comment: @AntonyMN I tried height 100% width auto and height auto width 100%, but I don't know how to combine them together

Answer (score 3):

You can manage this with `vmin`

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/eYNgaYZ)

> **vmin**
> Equal to the smaller of vw and vh.
>
> [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #000;
}

div {
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! however this does not vertically center the div, so I made some modifications: ```div {
  width:100vmin;
  height:100vmin;
  background: white;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  position:absolute;
}```

Comment: something more to ask, what if the div needs to be maintaining a 4:3 or 16:9 ratio?

Comment: How about cases not 1:1? say, 16:9? How is vmin used for that?

Comment: This only works for 1:1, I added an answer to the question with a formula which accounts for any aspect ratio.

Answer (score 3):

**vmin solution only works for 1:1 aspect ratio, use this general formula instead:**

```
width: min(<max-vw>vw, <max-vh * aspect-ratio>vh);
height: min(<max-vh>vh, <max-vw * inverse-aspect-ratio>vw);
```

- max-vw/max-vh = the maximum viewport percentage you want the container to occupy (in the example it would be 100, but you may use this to have padding around the container)
- aspect-ratio/inverse-aspect-ratio = you calculate the mathematical ratio and multiply it for the other number (max-vw or max-vh) (for 16:9 it would be: 16/9=1.778 and 9/16=0.56, respectively)

So, for 16:9 and no padding you would use:

```
width: min(100vw, 178vh);
height: min(100vh, 56vw);
```

Also, you might have noticed that the formula for 1:1 would be `width: min(100vw, 100vh)` which is the **exact
same as** `width: 100vmin`

#### Snippet for the three aspect ratios asked:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  font-weight: semibold;
  color: white;
  
  padding: 7px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ar-1-1 {
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 3;
  
  width: min(100vh, 100vw); /* RELEVANT LINE */
  height: min(100vh, 100vw); /* RELEVANT LINE */
}

.ar-4-3 {
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 2;
  
  width: min(100vw, 133vh); /* RELEVANT LINE */
  height: min(100vh, 75vw); /* RELEVANT LINE */
}

.ar-16-9 {
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 1;
  
  width: min(100vw, 178vh); /* RELEVANT LINE */
  height: min(100vh, 56vw); /* RELEVANT LINE */
}
```

```html
<div class="ar-1-1">1:1 with no padding</div>
<div class="ar-4-3">4:3 with no padding</div>
<div class="ar-16-9">16:9 with no padding</div>
```

*(the cards in the example are stacked in a way that can only be seen properly in a "widescreen" ratio)*

Answer (score -1):

Just create a wrapper div `wrapper` with a percentage value for `padding-bottom`, like:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 75%; /** For a 4:3 **/
}
```

This will cause `wrapper` to keep a 4:3 aspect ratio.
This is because:

> padding percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the
>   generated box's containing box

[Source: w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/box.html#padding-properties)

For any aspect ratio, divide `aspect ratio height/aspect ratio width` to get the `padding-bottom` value

```
aspect ratio / padding-bottom
-----------------------------
16:9         / 56.25%
4:3          / 75%
3:2          / 66.66%
8:5          / 62.5%
```

[Source: w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp)

Comment: this only applies to full width but not full height